# Display the results in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have this code where a user types a phrase or word and it reverses the string, but my problem is that I would like for it to display the results in the very same text box the user typed the word. Here’s my code:

```js
function revme() {
  var textb = document.getElementById("textb");
  var str = textb.value;
  var str1 = "";

  l = str.length;
  for (i = l; i >= 0; --i) {
    str1 = str1 + str.substring(i, i + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = str1;
}
```

```html
Please enter your text
<br>
<input type="text" id="textb">
<p id="results"></p>
<input type="button" value="Reverse" onclick="revme()">
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("textb").innerHTML = str1;
```

But that doesn’t work. Any Ideas?

Comment: use `document.getElementById("textb").value = str1`

Comment: its working in fiddle what's the problem & you put your question for text field and results shows to paragraph, please update and make a good question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're setting the `innerHTML` of textbox. Instead, you should set the `value` of the textbox.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p4xanz8u/)

```js
var textb = document.getElementById("textb");

function revme() {
  var str = textb.value;
  var str1 = "";

  l = str.length;
  for (i = l; i >= 0; --i) {
    str1 = str1 + str.substring(i, i + 1);
  }
  textb.value = str1;
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

```html
Please enter your text
<br>
<input type="text" id="textb">
<p id="results"></p>
<input type="button" value="Reverse" onclick="revme()">
```

Another way to reverse string will be using `string` and `array` functions as follow. I'll also recommend you to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p4xanz8u/1/)

```js
var textb = document.getElementById("textb");

document.getElementById('reverse').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var str = textb.value || '';
  textb.value = str.split('').reverse().join('');
}, false);
```

```html
Please enter your text
<br>
<input type="text" id="textb">
<p id="results"></p>
<input type="button" id="reverse" value="Reverse" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Let it done done by this .. i am getting the exact reverse pattern of any value i enter.

```
    <html>
<body>
Please enter your text<br>
<input type="text" id="textb">
<p id="results"></p>
<input type="button" value="Reverse" onclick="revme()">
</body>
<script>
function revme() {
var textb = document.getElementById("textb");
var str = textb.value;
var str1 = "";

l = str.length;
    for  (i = l ; i >=0 ; --i ){
        str1 = str1 + str.substring(i,i+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("textb").value= str1;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question `I would like for it to display the results in the very same text box`